# Pyspark on yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, pyspark

Is there any way to run pyspark scripts with yarn-cluster mode without using the spark-submit script?  I need it in this way because i will integrate this code into a django web app.

When i try to run any script in yarn-cluster mode i got the following error :

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Detected yarn-cluster mode, but isn't running on a cluster. Deployment to YARN is not supported directly by SparkContext. Please use spark-submit.
```

I'm creating the sparkContext in the following way :

```
        conf = (SparkConf()
            .setMaster("yarn-cluster")
            .setAppName("DataFrameTest"))

        sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

        #Dataframe code ....
```

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The reason `yarn-cluster` mode isn't supported is that `yarn-cluster` means bootstrapping the driver-program itself (e.g. the program calling using a SparkContext) onto a YARN container. Guessing from your statement about submitting from a django web app, it sounds like you want the python code that contains the SparkContext to be embedded in the web app itself, rather than shipping the driver code onto a YARN container which then handles a separate spark job.

This means your case most closely fits with `yarn-client` mode instead of `yarn-cluster`; in `yarn-client` mode, you can run your SparkContext code anywhere (like inside your web app), while it talks to YARN for the actual mechanics of running jobs.

Fundamentally, if you're sharing any in-memory state between your web app and your Spark code, that means you won't be able to chop off the Spark portion to run inside a YARN container, which is what `yarn-cluster` tries to do. If you're not sharing state, then you can simply invoke a subprocess which actually does call `spark-submit` to bundle an independent PySpark job to run in `yarn-cluster` mode.

To summarize:

1. If you want to embed your Spark code directly in your web app, you need to use `yarn-client` mode instead: SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client")
2. If the Spark code is loosely coupled enough that `yarn-cluster` is actually viable, you can issue a Python [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) to actually invoke `spark-submit` in `yarn-cluster` mode.

Comment: Python virtual environments further complicate this process.

Right now, I'm using a separate worker process to pick up jobs that the web app enqueues. This worker calls `spark-submit`. I am trying to share the virtual environment with the app and the worker. However, when I invoke yarn in `client` mode, it references the Python version from my virtual environment. Am I just missing something? How can I tell Spark to use Python installed on the nodes rather than the one inside the virtual environment?

Comment: @Michael In my spark-submit, I pass a virtual environment around with the spark job, and reference the python from within there to run my python code since I can't control the workers in my corp only the code.)  There were 2 pieces to it, 1 make a python env that is binary compatible with your worker OS (I used a docker container) and then shipping and referencing that virtual env.  To ship it -- use:
**--archives python35.zip#MY_ALIAS** and then to tell spark to use it --
 `--conf "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=./MY_ALIAS/python35/bin/python3"`
Hope this helps.