# Error initializing SparkContext using yarn-cluster mode

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a simple code to create a file on hdfs and write contents to it and close that file. I am able to run this code in local mode as well as on yarn-client mode. But when i run the same code with yarn-cluster mode I am getting 
as `Error initializing SparkContext`.

Scala Code I have used in as below:

```
object Main {
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val conf= new SparkConf()

var sparkContext =new SparkContext("yarn-cluster","testHdfsWrite",conf)
val uri = URI.create (hdfslocation); // hdfs location of my home directory
val confi = new Configuration();
val file = FileSystem.get(uri, confi);
val os = file.create(new Path(uri))
os.write("Hello World".getBytes("UTF-8"))
os.close()
 }
}
```

This code successfully creates a file and writes a content "Hello World" to it when I use **local** mode and **yarn-client** mode. But when I use **yarn-cluster** mode I get below exception.

```
 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Detected yarn-cluster mode, but isn't running on a cluster. Deployment to YARN is not supported directly by SparkContext. Please use spark-submit.
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:147)
        at Main$.main(Main.scala:17)
        at Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
```

I have already saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31327275/pyspark-on-yarn-cluster-mode) and most of the related links. but it is different that what I expect. If you have a correct link please share or if you know how to resolve this issue please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: Show us how you are submitting the application? Is it through IDE or you submit the runnable?

Answer (score 4):

I also faced this issue and tried to resolve it using below:
Try this,create 'spark context' within main() method of your program(same for sql context) as:

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit =
    {

```
  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")

  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

}
And import below:

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf

import org.apache.spark.SparkContext

Run your code using below command for cluster mode and don't set 'yarn-cluster' in your code,provide it while submitting job in cluster using below:

**spark-submit --master yarn-cluster --packages < package name> --class com.Test.ExampleTest < hadoop path of your program jar> --jars < Other jars>**

Comment: Dear khushbu kanojia, is there any way to doing this whithout spark-submit? directly from code

Answer (score 0):

Error message states you must use spark-submit to launch the app. Are you launching it with spark-submit?

Answer (score 0):

try instead of

```
val conf= new SparkConf()

var sparkContext =new SparkContext("yarn-cluster","testHdfsWrite",conf)
```

to use

```
val conf= new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("testHdfsWrite")
      .setMaster("yarn-cluster")

var sparkContext = new SparkContext(conf)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit application (especially in cluster mode), you should provide mode information to spark-submit script. Thus just use following parameters to start your application:

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster test_2.10-1.0.jar
```